# mutiple radio's in a form (PHP)

Tags: php, html, forms

I created a form and I want multiple radio questions in my form with the same output (Yes,No ).
Here is my script:

```
<?php
echo '<tr>
    <script>
            function displayResult(check)
            {
                document.getElementById("result").value=check
            }
    </script>
    <td width="60%">'
        .$row1['vraag'].'
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="radio" name="check" onclick="displayResult(this.value)" value="ja">Ja
        <input type="radio" name="check" onclick="displayResult(this.value)" value="nee">Nee
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="hidden" name="vragen'.$aantalBranches.'[]" value="'.$row1['vraag'].'"/>
        <input id="result" type="text" name="antwoorden'.$aantalBranches.'[]"/>
    </td>
</tr>';
```

As you can see I sent the question with it (vragen) and the answer (antwoorden) when the form is filled.
The problem I have now is when I select the second question also with a radio the output of the first one also changes.
Anyone can help me in the right direction with radio button ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All radio buttons with the same `name` are treated as being in the same group - and only one item from the group can be selected at the same time.  So, your second set of radio boxes need their `name` set to a different group to the `name` used by the first.

Comment: U can maybe help me how to get a unique name with every name ?